# storing data and access it

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c, visual-studio-2010

What is the best way to store data & fastest way to access it, that is free and doesn't require additional stuff to install ?

Comment: Well what is the language? What kind of data you are talking about. Do you want to store the data in the memory or what? You should really think about this question a bit more carefully. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Sounds like you want the fine capabilities associated with Text Files. We have a nice 2005 Model here, with the upgraded touring trim =D

Comment: "best" and "fastest" are rarely compatible.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?  If free and nothing to install is absolute, then I would suggest Adrian's answer below and look at XML.  If you're looking at a size able amount of data there are free databases but they do require installations.

Comment: I will play devil's advocate here: my answer is good depending what you want to do. If you're looking for self contained files, by-design-exportable, that are both human and machine readable/writable and you are not going to processes 10 of thousand of objects inside of it, you should go with XML. If not, you should take a look at @Otavio Decio's suggestion, which is SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the language is C, you could use `structs` and `fread()` & `fwrite()` to save the data into single "database" file. It is not the most compatible way but it certainly is fast. And it doesn't require any additional stuff to be installed.

Comment: In what kind of databse file type would you recommend ?

Comment: Well you can craft your own db format for your dataset. It is certainly the most efficient way. Using SQLite is easier and more portable.

Answer (score 3):

Use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: I tried firebird, is this any similar ?

Answer (score 3):

XML. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703783/what-would-be-a-good-approch-for-using-xml-as-data-persistence-for-a-small-c-app). Keep in mind that by using XML, you have a machine-structured human-readable file.

**Update**

Since this apparently looks very new to OP, here are some links:

About XML:

- [XML Very Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)

About Accessing XML from C#.NET

- [Microsoft Linq TO XML Doc/Howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)
- [A nice Linq to XML Tutorial](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/)

Comment: XML is very slow compared to Google ProtoBuf's and JSON. Just FYI (no downvote).

Comment: I never tried XML, does this have any special build-in formatting like rtf or docx ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But .Net provides native access to it. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp). This is where you'll learn the basics for XML.

Comment: so this is like html or php, i know that. So basically i could store data in a html too or ?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of like HTML, but it's not. You define a document structure and then follow it. HTML is about exhibition. XML is about data. PHP is something else. Tell you what: take your time, read a little more about XML. And about everything we've been writing about here. We're just guiding, but you must find the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader` to read files 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

and 
`StreamWriter` to write files
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

They are both classes included in the .NET framework.

Comment: Well i guess this is fast, but is it the fastest way ?

Comment: it removes all the associated overhead with things such as XMLDocument parsing. It doesn't get much faster than directly telling the computer to write or read from disk

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/01/13/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download-and-use-with-webmatrix.aspx) - it's free, file based, requires no extra installation and this also gives you a nice upgrade path since it also supports Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a relational database, use the [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.) ADO.Net wrapper around the Sqlite database. Drop the DLL into your project and you get a free, fast, single-file SQL database.

If all you need is a key-value store, then use [Persistent Dictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation&referringTitle=Home) in the ESENT managed interface.