# Persisting with XML: multiple files or single file?

Tags: c#, xml

I've already about general guidelines on [What would be a good approch for using XML as data persistence for a small C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703783/what-would-be-a-good-approch-for-using-xml-as-data-persistence-for-a-small-c-app).

I decide to use XML under the hood. It's a small app, a report card app for teacher use. These are my main entities:

- Student
- Course
- Teacher (there should be only one, but I'll store it because of future integration possibilities)
- Grade (a student can have more than one grade in each course)

I have some points I would like suggestions:

- Under the hood, should I have one XML file per entity or one big XML file?

  - How's that under a performance perspective
  - How's that under a data joining perspective
- Under the hood, should I use Linq to XML? Is there something else to even be considered?

Comment: I assume this is a desktop rather than a web app?

Comment: Yes, it is. For now, it's a offline stand-alone. It might evolve, time will tell. So I decided: it should be a simple as possible. Not even use embedded DB. It should produce a file. XML is human-machine-readable-writable. So it's the obvious choice. The file should not be that big. One teacher has like 100 students tops. One teacher teaches around 3 to 6 courses. I'm even thinking on building it on mobile. But I want to stick to C# because Linq would make my life easier. I'm just wondering about the single x multiple files dilemma. What should I consider? What am I not considering?

Comment: If insisting upon pain, another option may be to use the "old" DataTable/DataSet and let those automatically serialize. (I would recommend SQLite or similar as relationships/DQL are wonderful!) XML doesn't "buy" much unless it needs to be hand edited or is used as an interchange format (e.g. used elsewhere). Actually, using XML as an untyped data-object w/ XPath is another nicety of XML, but I think someone will stab me for that ;-)

Comment: Just doing ballpark figures for the data size, Figure 25 teachers, each with 1k of data.  400 Students, each with 2k of data.  75 courses, each with 5k of data.  If this is the scale of data, You're talking about ~1mb.  This is easily within a reasonable size for XML Serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One XML file is probably easier.

That file might look like this:

```
<ReportCardData>
    <Students> 
       <Student>...data for student A ...</Student>
          ...
    </Students>
    <Teachers>
       <Teacher> ...
         ...
    </Teachers>
    <Courses>
       <Course> ...
          ...
    </Courses>
 </ReportCardData>
```

The code in C# would look like this:

```
public class ReportCardData 
{
   public List<Student> Students;
   public List<Teacher> Teachers;
   public List<Course> Courses;
}
```

And the code to de-serialize (read) the data looks like this:

```
ReportCardData rcd = null;
var s= new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportCardData>));
using(System.IO.StreamReader reader= System.IO.File.OpenText(filepath))
{
    rcd= (ReportCardData) s.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

...be sure to add in the appropriate exception handling, etc.

Using XML Serialization works fine for something like this, even for large data sets with multiple tens of megabytes. (If you are talking about 100's of Megabytes of data, then maybe consider a real database like SQL Express)

The reading and writing performance will likely be fine. 
Keep in mind that when you de-serialize data from the XML file, the entire dataset will be held in memory in your app. So if it is 15mb worth of grade data, then it is all in memory at one time.

You also asked about a "data joining perspective" - not sure what that means, but using Linq to XML you can perform queries across that data. The performance of the in-memory queries is also fine.

Comment: I see where you're getting... So, I could load the 4 sets in memory when file is loaded (say, I'll have 4 List<MyEntity>). User can then play around. When user hits Save, all is saved into the XML. This is one scenario. The other would be save at each interaction (say, if it's a mobile app). What do you think of the first approach? On the second, how would I minimize performance issues? Can optimally I save just a fraction of the XML file?

Comment: I'd recommend the first approach. Load it all and save it all in one go. Your 4 Lists would be all part of one class - one nested object that gets serialized and de-serialized. If you are truly concerned with performance you can change things around a little. Once in a mobile app I had a very large XML database, that I did not want to retain in memory. I designed it to read and *index* the XML file. When the user wanted drilldown, or to update, I would seek in the XML file to the indexed position, and read + update only a segment of the large XML file, a few child elements only.

Comment: The only way to know what will be appropriate and practical for your case is to prototype it and start playing around and measuring it. You could, for example, combine the approaches I described, and use de-serialization to read in the entire file, but use an XmlWriter to save only a portion of the data, upon update.